# Unreachable partition on LINUX server

Tags: linux, centos, mount, partition, backup

I'm posting here to have your points of view on my problem.

Part of my job is to manage backup servers but I'm new in LINUX world.

Today I had to repair a backup server running on CentOS 6.xx.

The problem is that the backup was set up to save the server data on an external hard drive. The hard drive was supposed to be mounted on sde1 part.
But one day, the sde1 part became unreachable and the external HDD part became sdf1, screwing the backup.

So my question is : what can cause this to happen? Do you have an idea why, suddenly, sde1 became unusable? Can it be a hardware issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably find why by running `dmesg` (or looking in `/var/log/kern.log`, or running `journalctl -bk`—sorry not sure which of these are around on CentOS). For some reason the disk disconnected, then later reconnected. `sde` was already in use, so the kernel gave the drive the next available: `sdf`. The disconnect/reconnect was probably a hardware problem (but maybe something non-worrying, like someone bumping a USB cable).

Ultimately, however, `/dev/sd?` are *not* stable. At minimum, if you have two identical external USB disks, you can expect them to flip around randomly every boot. Internal drive letter assignments are often much more stable, but you should really use `/dev/disk/by-id/` (or any of the `/dev/disk/by-*/` directories), a filesystem UUID, etc. With USB (or Firewire), `by-path` is best avoided (changing which USB port something is plugged in to is *not* supposed to matter—but that changes the path).

Comment: The comment about /dev/sd* not being stable goes double for any type of external storage, but especially with USB, where depending on your hardware, you may get random resets because of adding or removing _other_ devices on the bus (or other devices being poorly behaved and triggering bus resets).

Comment: Ok thanks, i didn't even know about UUID. The problem is that the client has to switch between to external HDD and the backup setting accepts only one partition (sdf1 now). I fear that sde1 reappear and desappear again and again or maybe it's blocked forever...

Comment: And the client has to switch the 2 external HDD every day so it should take back the sde1 part... But it doesn't, that's why i guess there's a bigger problem here...

Comment: @ViouYek something is still references sde, so the kernel can't re-use it. E.g., maybe it's still mounted somewhere (though of course any access to the mount will just error out). If you can't find what's referencing it, a reboot will free it up. Your best bet might be to write a custom udev rule to keep a symlink to the correct device (if you need help writing a udev rule, that's probably best asked as a new question—if we don't already have it)

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, i'll look at udev rule asap.